# Is there a name for an associative and commutative magma (groupoid)?

Tags: abstract-algebra

An associative magma is said to be a semigroup. A semigroup with identity is said to be a monoid... Is there a name for an associative and commutative algebra?

Comment: Modern useage of groupoid referred to a category where all morphisms are isomorphisms. A one object groupoid is a group, with composition of morphisms are the group operation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid

Answer (score 2):

The standard term is just "commutative semigroup".